# vba code for sending texts from excel to whatsapp

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, whatsapp

I have previously used selenium webdriver for sending messages to whatsapp via VBA. But now, I need some pure vba codes to send text from excel sheet. What I discovered InternetExplorer does not support whatsapweb. I searched the internet I discovered some tutorial where it uses APPACTIVATE method for using CHROME.

```
AppActivate "Chrome"
```

But I was not able to use chrome with this code. Can anyone help with code below/ suggesting links will also be benefital for sending messages through vba to whatsapp without third party applications.

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()

'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
 
    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True
 
    'Define URL
    URL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
 
    'Navigate to URL
    IE.navigate URL
 
    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
 
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
 
    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"
    
    'Unload IE
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

On internet I saw excel formula where it hyperlinks the text message to whatsapp from formula bar, but HYPERLINK formula opens the edge browser not IE. Could not I use also Edge browser in vba library instead IE.Application?

```
=IF(G3="","",HYPERLINK("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%2B"&VLOOKUP(B3,'Employee Master'!A:D,4,0)&"&text=" & H3&"&app_absent=1&send=1",")"))
```

Comment: Yeah, Windows 11 killed Iexplorer, and Iexplorer internet controls along with it. 
If you want to do web crawling try selenium.